# Opening a file in excel without recalculating NOW()

Tags: excel

In excel 2010, 2011, and 2013 (tried all three) opening a file as read-only still recalculates NOW(). Is there a way to instruct excel not to recalculate when opening a file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way is to switch the automatic (Default) Calculation option to manual.

[image]

**update:**
Open a blank new Excel workbook first, then set the manual calculation option as described above. Then go to File -> open and chose the file you want to open without any recalculating. This will overwrite the calculating option no matter which mode the file was saved in.

Comment: Nirk, have you read the update? Open a new workbook and change to manual calculation option. After that you might open your file without taking risks for any recalculating.

Comment: `Calculation Options` > `Manual` is on the **Formulas** tab.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to get at the information is make a reference the data in the cells via another workbook, while the target workbook is closed.

For example, in the target workbook (call it "Target.xlsx", , "Sheet1" is the worksheet, and it's located in C:\), say there is a value in cell A1 which is **=NOW()** and has the value 2015/01/01.

While keeping the target sheet closed, now open a new workbook and point to Target.xlsx value in Sheet1!$A$1 as a cell formula:

**='C:\[Target.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1**

Now, assuming all of your pointers are correct, it will give you the value of the target worksheet as **2015/01/01** without you opening the original target workbook and disturbing the contents.

Comment: I like this method - allows you to stop Now() from recalculating until you enable links in the workbook, while still allowing all other formulas to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Open a blank workbook and go to file and open the target file that you need to open. Next to the open button click the drop-down menu and click repair and use the extract option if you just want to retrieve the values or use repair if you want to repair the excel sheet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33459166)