# Excel: Get current values of volatile functions saved in file

Tags: excel, volatile

I've got an Excel file with several thousand cells that have volatile functions. I need to save a record of the values of those functions the last time the file was open. When I open the file, I see the old values in the part of the worksheet that is visible, but those values are quickly replaced with new, recalculated ones. How can I save a record of the old values that are currently stored in the file?

Comment: Perhaps the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597706/opening-a-file-in-excel-without-recalculating-now

Answer (score 0):

The link in @BigBen's comment is to a special case of my question where the volatile function is now(). That question had two answers, which each suggested a method to do what I needed. I tried the first one, and it worked. That method was to:

- Open a blank workbook.
- Set "Formulas > Calculation Options" to "Manual".
- Open the file with the volatile functions.

When I did that, the file opened with the old values, and they didn't update. I made a note of the formulas in the cells with the volatile functions, and then replaced those formulas with their values (copy, then Alt-S-V) so the cells would never again recalculate. The file then became a permanent record of the old values of those cells.

Mission accomplished!